# PHP: Distinct categories and multiple subcategories?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get distinct category name and get all the subcategories related to each category name from mysql database using PHP.

so I need it to look like this:

```
Cat1
sub_cat1
sub_cat2
sub_cat3

Cat2
sub_cat1
sub_cat2

Cat3
sub_cat1
sub_cat2
sub_cat3
sub_cat4
```

this is my code:

```
$subs = "";
$header_list = "";

$sql2 ="SELECT * FROM sub_cats GROUP BY cat_name";
$query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql2);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query2); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $scid = $row["id"];
             $scat_name = $row["cat_name"];
             $scsub_cat_name = $row["sub_cat_name"];

             foreach ((array) $scsub_cat_name as $item) {
                 $subs .='<li>
                        <a href="printing-products/standard-business-cards-range25d3.html?productTypeId=3#?pt=3&amp;lt=1&amp;ps=57&amp;pat=4&amp;prt=1">'.$scsub_cat_name.' <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right"></i></a>
                    </li>';

                 }

             $header_list .= '<li class="product-types">
                <span class="heading">'.$scat_name.'</span>
                <ul class="product-options">
                '.$subs.'
                </ul>
            </li>';

            /*foreach ((array) $cat_name as $item) {}*/

    }
} else {
    $header_list = "";
}

echo $header_list ;
```

The issue that I am facing is that it will get distinct categories properly but it will not get the sub-categories related to each category properly and it will put them under different categories!

all the categories and subcategories are stored in the same table in the mysql database like so:

```
id   cat_name   sub_cat_name
1    cat1       subcat1
2    cat1       subcat2
3    cat1       subcat3
4    cat2       subcat1
5    cat2       subcat2

etc etc.....
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is what I've done and I created a third table `table_cat_sub_cat` in mysql database:

```
$sql2 ="SELECT catgories.cat_name, sub_cats.sub_cat_name 
FROM catgories 
INNER JOIN table_cat_sub_cat ON catgories.id=table_cat_sub_cat.cat_id 
INNER JOIN sub_cats ON table_cat_sub_cat.sub_cat_id = sub_cats.id";
$query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql2);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query2); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             //$scid = $row["id"];
             $scat_name = $row["cat_name"];
             $scsub_cat_name = $row["sub_cat_name"];

             foreach ((array) $scsub_cat_name as $item) {
                 $subs .='<li>
                        <a href="printing-products/standard-business-cards-range25d3.html?productTypeId=3#?pt=3&amp;lt=1&amp;ps=57&amp;pat=4&amp;prt=1">'.$scsub_cat_name.' <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right"></i></a>
                    </li>';

                 }

             $header_list .= '<li class="product-types">
                <span class="heading">'.$scat_name.'</span>
                <ul class="product-options">
                '.$subs.'
                </ul>
            </li>';
```

but i still get some strange output and *subcategories are going under unrelated categories!*

Comment: Could you please share your structure in case of two tables..i.e., join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the correct way of doing this if anyone's faced the same issue in the future.**

```
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', );

    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    };


    // Perform queries
    $sql1 = 'select * from catgories';
    $result1 = $db->query($sql1);

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($result1 as $menu)
    {
         echo "<li>".$menu["cat_name"];
         echo "<ul>";
         $menu_title = $menu["cat_name"];

        $sql2 = 'SELECT
        sub_cats.sub_cat_name
        FROM
        sub_cats
        INNER JOIN catgories ON sub_cats.cat_name = catgories.cat_name
        WHERE
        catgories.cat_name = "'.$menu_title.'"';    

        $result2 = $db->query($sql2);
        foreach ($result2 as $submenu)
        {
            echo "<li>".$submenu["sub_cat_name"]."</li>";
        }
         echo "</ul>";
         echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";


    $db->close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create 3 tables: `categories`, `subcategories`, `connections`. In `categories` you have `category_id` and `category_name`, in `subcategories` you have `subcategory_id` and `subcategory_name`, in `connections` you have `connection_id`, `category_id`, `subcategory_id`. Then you can easily modify one subcategory in all categories, you can easily manage them.

Query:

```
SELECT categories.category_name, subcategories.subcategory_name
FROM subcategories
INNER JOIN connections ON connections.subcategory_id = subcategories.subcategory_id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id = connections.category_id
```

**EDIT**

No no no author.

```
$query= mysql_query($conn, $yourQuery);
$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
    $subcat_name = $row['sub_cat_name'];
    if(!isset($results[$cat_name])){
        $results[$cat_name] = array();
    }
    $results[$cat_name][] = $subcat_name;
}

if(!empty($results)){
    foreach($results as $category => $subcats){
        echo $category . "\n";
        foreach($subcats as $subcategory){
            echo $subcategory . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: please view my edit! i did follow your suggestion but I still get the same result! which is subcategories are going under different categories! also, the categories are being repeated multiple times which is an unwanted action! did you leave the GROUP BY by accident or?

Comment: @H.HISTORY I don't work on weekend, I will try to help the fastes how I can ;)

Answer (score 0):

you must separate categories and subcategories in 2 different tables so many categories can relate to many subcategories

```
table_cat
id   cat_name   
1    cat1       
2    cat2
3    cat3
....

table_sub_cat
id   sub_cat_name   
1    sub_cat1       
2    sub_cat2
3    sub_cat3
....

table_cat_sub_cat
id_cat    id_sub_cat
1         1
1         3
2         1
2         2
2         3
....
```

Then you could

```
SELECT table_cat.cat_name, table_sub_cat.sub_cat_name 
FROM table_cat 
LEFT JOIN table_cat_sub_cat ON table_cat.id=table_cat_sub_cat.id_cat 
INNER JOIN table_sub_cat ON table_cat_sub_cat.id_sub_cat = table_sub_cat.id;
```

Comment: i have done that also and I tried to join tables but i had no luck.

Comment: Did you try it like this?

Comment: Yes, please view my edit. also, you are missing a id at the end of your query. you accidentally typed i instead of id.